# Move cells to the left in pandas DataFrame bsed on groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. 
For A =2, I want to move all non -9999999 cells to the left while preserving the order from left to right for the columns which starts with "X"

```
data=[[0,1,0,0, 0],
      [1,2,0,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0,1],
      [2,4,0,0,1],
      [2,-9999999,0,0,0],
      [3,-9999999, 0,0,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','X_1','X_2', 'X_3','E'])
df

My expected output:

   A      X_1      X_2      X_3  E
0  0        1        0        0  0
1  1        2        0        0  0
2  2        0        0        0  1
3  2        4        0        0  1
4  2        0        0 -9999999  0
5  3 -9999999        0        0  1
```

UPDATED DATAFRAME:

```
data=[[0,1,0,0, 0],
      [1,2,0,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0,1],
      [2,4,0,0,1],
      [2,0,-9999999,0,0],
      [3,-9999999, 0,0,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','X_1','X_2', 'X_3','E'])
df
```

Comment: What do you mean with *I want to move all non -9999999 cells to the left while preserving the order from left to right for the columns which starts with "X"* ? In your example only  -9999999 is moved

Comment: Yes, in my example for row where A=2, all non -9999999 has moved to the left in the expected output and -9999999 to the rightmost only for the columns which starts with "X"

Comment: please check my answer @Shanoo

Comment: please check now:)

Comment: I think that if you execute the code you have put in your question (which I wrote on the other hand) you will get the correct solution too ...

Comment: Be careful not to run it several times because then I would turn..

Comment: `df.loc[df['A']==2, df.columns.str.startswith('X')] = df.loc[df['A']==2, df.columns.str.startswith('X')].apply(lambda x: \
       pd.Series(x[x.ne(-9999999)].tolist() + [-9999999]*(len(x) - x.ne(-9999999).sum().astype(int)), index=x.index), axis=1)`

Comment: But you need to understand that this code shifts all -9999999 to the rightand others to right. I am not sure that this is what you;ve asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Basically i want to shift all non -9999999 to the left and -9999999 should be in the rightmost*

```
df.loc[df['A']==2, df.columns.str.startswith('X')] = \
df.loc[df['A']==2, df.columns.str.startswith('X')] \
  .apply(lambda x: \
     pd.Series(x[x.ne(-9999999)].tolist() + \
               [-9999999]*(len(x) - x.ne(-9999999).sum().astype(int)), \
               index=x.index), \
          axis=1)
```

Comment: This code doesn't work on huge datasets. Though the logic is correct

Comment: apply in any case  is very slow. But I can't do it without loop.